# how to update stack array from form react

Tags: reactjs

My data looks like this. I have a form with registerName, address, mode, size, por and doc which will add a new object in data. However, I want now to update only field level with a submit form. How can I do with setstate.

> data: [
> {
> registerName: "MANID",
> address: 0,
> mode: "R",
> size: 8,
> por: 0,
> doc: "document level",
> fields: [
> { bitname: 'INT', bitmask: '16', bitvalue: '0', maskname: 'INT_MASK', doc: 'doc level' },
> ]
> },
> ],

Answer (score 0):

Well I manage to find the answer at the end:

> 

```
 datas: [this.state.data.map(                          
>                           (row, j) => {
>                             if (row.registerName === submission.registerName) {
>                               return {
>                                 ...row,
>                                 row: row.fields.push(submission),                                         
>                               }
>                             }
>                             return {data : row }                          
>                           },
>                           
>                         )]
```